# Different Destructor Types?

Tags: c++, copy, destructor

I have an object called a Chunk that holds a pointer to a b2Body. It does other important things, but i removed those for simplicity. Heads up, smart pointers won't work(I think), you'll see why.

```
class DChunk
{
public:
    DChunk();

    DChunk(const DChunk& old);
    virtual ~DChunk();

    virtual b2Body* getBody() const;

private:
    b2Body* m_pBody;//pointer;
};
```

The question is, how to define when to delete the m_pBody object.

If I want to copy this object, like say there is a vector of these things and I push_back another, it will call the Copy Constructor, copy the memory address of m_pBody(thats what i want), and then delete the old one. If the Destructor on this object deletes m_pBody, that's obviously bad, because the new copy wont have a valid memory address, but if it doesn't delete it, then m_pBody will never be deleted, and it needs to be deleted when there are no more Chunks pointing at it.

The only correct way to delete the m_pBody object is to call m_pBody->GetWorld()->DestroyBody( m_pBody ); and thats not under my control, so smart pointers dont really work. 
I was hoping there would be different types of destructors that get called appropriately, like when a copy has been made in a vector. Also, there should never be more than one Chunk associated with one b2Body, if that is helpful.

Comment: Does `m_pBody` have to be pointer?

Comment: You could use a smart pointer that has a custom deleter. C++11 provides them, Boost has them, and you could also make your own.

Comment: 1. Yes, must be a pointer.

2. I don't think I have access to C++11. I guess I could use Boost if I REALLY needed to, but I would rather avoid putting more libraries into this project. I was going to make my own, but I figured there was a more classic way of handling it.

Comment: If you want to use my solution, I recommend to upgrade from VS 2010 Express to VS 2013 Express. http://www.visualstudio.com/downloads/download-visual-studio-vs#d-express-windows-desktop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will assume you have something like

```
    vector<DChunck> myvec;
```

and you are worried about doing

```
    obj=DChunk()
    myvec.push_back(obj)
```

First of all (this is very beginner friendly approach, avoiding smart pointers or any C++11) there's something not quite correct about creating a container DChunk objects. That's because when you declare

```
    vector<DChunk>
```

you are telling your vector that it will receive objects the size of DChunk. 
However, since that class contains a pointer to an array, m_pBody (array's size will not be constant!), this approach will not be too "healthy" for C++.
Given this, you can do something else, sticking to your class design: create a container of pointers! 
You can create

```
    vector<DChunk*> myvec;
```

and if you want to add an object to that vector, you just do

```
    DChunk *obj = new DChunk();
    myvec.push_back(event);
```

since now the container is handling pointers, which can be juggled around without interfering with the objects content, avoiding the worries concerning a destructor.
Calling an object's method will now be, for example,

```
    (*myvec[3]).getBody()
```

or (cleaner version)

```
    myvec[3]->getBody()
```

Hope I addressed your question

Comment: Yeah, I knew that was an option too, and I did that in other parts of the project, but I was trying to avoid using vectors of pointer, because of the overhead in dereferencing. Unless of course that object is really big. But I suppose in this case that would be the best solution.

Some other things though, m_pBody is not an array. Ironically though, DChunk does contains a vector of pointers that I removed to make it easier to read.

Comment: Well, the nice thing about this container of pointers design is that it is so versatile, you don't really have to care what's inside your objects. However, if the DChunk object contains a vector of pointers itself, that might get a bit tricky indeed!

Answer (score 0):

You can also provide move constructor so that instead of copying, it would move stuff... Here's an example that I made some hours ago, because I had the same problem (I didn't know in what order would these constructors and when be called, also "&&" is move constructor):

A move constructor is similar to copy constructor. The difference is that in move constructor instead of copying values and stuff, you assign given object's pointers (not copy) and values to a new one (this->temp = OldClass.temp) and then make OldClass.temp = NULL; so that when the unavoidable destructor is called, it finds a NULL pointer and does not delete it.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>

class MyClass
{
public:
    MyClass()
    {
        temp = new RECT();
        ZeroMemory(temp, sizeof(RECT));
    }
    MyClass(int x, int y)
    {
        temp = new RECT();
        ZeroMemory(temp, sizeof(RECT));
        temp->left = x;
        temp->top = y;
    }
    MyClass(MyClass &&OldClass)
    {
        if (this->temp != NULL)
        {
            delete this->temp;
            this->temp = NULL;
        }
        temp = OldClass.temp;
        OldClass.temp = NULL;
    }
    MyClass& operator=(MyClass &&OldClass)
    {
        if (this->temp != NULL)
        {
            delete this->temp;
            this->temp = NULL;
        }
        temp = OldClass.temp;
        OldClass.temp = NULL;
        return *this;
    }
    MyClass(const MyClass &OldClass)
    {
        *temp = *OldClass.temp;
    }
    MyClass& operator=(const MyClass &OldClass)
    {
        *temp = *OldClass.temp;
        return *this;
    }
    ~MyClass()
    {
        if (this->temp != NULL)
        {
            delete this->temp;
            this->temp = NULL;
        }
    }
    void Print()
    {
        std::cout << temp << " " << temp->left << " " << temp->top << " " << temp->right << " " << temp->bottom << '\n';
    }
private:
    RECT *temp;
};

int main()
{
    MyClass bla, cha(54, 48);
    bla.Print();
    cha.Print();
    bla = MyClass(2, 2);
    bla.Print();
    bla = cha;
    bla.Print();
    cha = MyClass(54, 2);
    cha.Print();
    std::cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for commenting, and this is probably what I want, but I don't fully understand what's going on, could you explain it a bit?

Comment: a move constructor requires `C++11` if not "emulated" with other libraries like `boost`, at this point the other options are way better and the main focus of the problem it's still unsolved.

Comment: Well, the same story with DirectX9... Why use a newer one when we can use 10 years old one (If I think correctly that it was released in 2004). It should be mandatory by now to use C++11

Comment: But then again, only now I have read that he didn't have access to C++11... My bad.

Comment: @Helix You are completely wrong. Software is always created with specific target/dev platform in mind and migrations slows development process and raises overall cost. Beside, as for now you can at least use a small subset of C++11. MSVC, which is the most popular C++ compiler for Windows, still has poor support for its best features: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh567368.aspx. Also, there are often problems with compatibility. After we switched to VS2012, we were forced to wait for almost 6 months before NVidia released NSight Studio with support for the new toolchain.

Comment: @Mateusz Grzejek And you are completely right. I hate to admit, but I was more focused on DirectX's slow adaptation and completely disregarded other things you mentioned. What I wanted to say is that you should use newest C++ libraries whenever you can (word "mandatory" sounded better in my head).

Comment: Well, DirectX evolution is a hard topic. IMO the main factor was that many games (like The Witcher 2) have shown, that you can create stunning visual experience without using the newest technology. As for C++11, we moved for it's features, because new version of our project is created from scratch. However, not so long ago (few months) we were compiling the old one with VC6 (!). Many other companies have the very same issue - moving to new technology is easy (well, not always), but convincing your clients to do the same is sometimes an impossible task :)

Answer (score 0):

In common, a proper memory management is non trivial task and no universal decision are existing. Some simple and common well-known methods are presented as "smart pointer" types in newest libraries (and you can also define them yourself (by copy known "standard definition")). But it also is not an completely universal :-)
And your question seems to be a question for a such universal solution.
Some other programming languages (java ... , not C++) advertise you to get rid of that problem (by the built-in methods of language implementations).
You write: "Also, there should never be more than one Chunk associated with one b2Body, if that is helpful." . And then the problem seems to disappear (because the Chunk cannot be copied at all). (?)

Comment: Proper memory management IS a VERY trivial task. You allocate memory when you need it and deallocate when it's not used anymore. The real problem is to properly describe lifetime of each object and interactions between their contents. Also, I would not recommend so called 'smart pointers' so thoughtlessly. In fact it's quite heavy machinery, that can produce great performance impact if used improperly. Many C++ coders and companies use them even when they are not needed - just because everyone else uses them.